# Basic Haskell Functions

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to learn the basics. I need to declare a type called Pos for position that will have two integers and then I need to have the Directions North,South,West, East so that I can alter the position based on the direction.
Once I do that I need to make a function called moves that will take a list of moves and the initial position and return the position after all the moves.
Here is my code but I am stuck at the point that I have to iterate through the list of moves.

```
type Pos = (Int, Int)
data Direction = North | South | East | West

move :: Direction -> Pos -> Pos
move North (x,y) = (x, y+1)
move West (x,y) = (x-1, y)
move South (x,y) = (x, y-1)
move East (x,y) = (x+1, y)

moves :: [Direction] -> Pos -> Pos
moves [] (x,y) = (x,y)
moves (h:xs) (x,y) 
        | h == North = move North (x,y)
        | h == West  = move West (x,y)
        | h == South = move South (x,y)
        | otherwise  = move East (x,y)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You do not *have* to "iterate". Think *recursively*. You have a starting point `p` and a sequence `m1,...,mn` of moves. To perform the moves you first perform the move `m1` on the starting point `p`, and thus you reach a point `p'`. Now you have to perform moves `m2,...,mn` with starting point `p'`... which is the same problem as before but with different parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either before or after the single move corresponding to `h`, you need to make a *recursive* call to `moves` for the rest of the `Direction`s. If before, then each case becomes something like:

```
move North (moves xs (x,y))
```

if you want it to be after, which is probably the right approach given the problem specification, then it would be:

```
moves xs (move North (x,y))
```

However repeating the case analysis in `moves` is a bit unnecessary as you can just call `move` directly with `h`, e.g.

```
moves (h:xs) (x,y) = moves xs (move h (x,y))
```

In fact you don't even need to explicitly pattern-match on the `(x,y)` tuple;

```
moves (h:xs) pos = moves xs (move h pos)
```

As another answer points out, this is the same as the built-in `foldl` function (up to the arguments order), but it's probably best to understand how to do it by hand first.

Comment: I think it makes it clearer if you use `moves (h:xs) (x,y) = moves xs (move h (x,y))`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had to use guardians to check what kind of move was in the list...

Answer (score 9):

Combining a list of things into one thing is called folding the list. There are (approximately) two list folds: `foldl` and `foldr`. Leaning to use folds is an important step in learning Haskell. We need `foldl`, which has type

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

Now `foldl` works by using a combining function and an initial value to combine the stuff in a list, so for example

```
foldl (£) s [x,y,z] = (((s £ x) £ y) £ z)
```

(The `l` in `foldl` is short for left, so it's there to help you remember that your starting value `s` will end up at the left but more importantly that the brackets are associated to the left.)

The third argument is a list argument `[b]`. We'll use that for the list of moves, so the type `b` will be `Direction`.

The second argument is a starting value of type `a`, so we'll use that for your initial position, so type `a` will be `Pos`.

The first argument is a function to combine something from your list with a current value. Now that we know the types `b` and `a` are `Direction` and `Pos` we know that our combining function must have type `Pos -> Direction -> Pos`. The move function is almost exactly what we need, except we need to swap the arguments. The `flip` function does that, so `flip move` has the type we need.

So we'll specialise the type of `foldl` to be

```
foldl :: (Pos -> Direction -> Pos) -> Pos -> [Direction] -> Pos
```

and define

```
moves :: [Direction] -> Pos -> Pos
moves ds i = foldl (flip move) i ds
```

---

Now `foldl` has a "strict" version called `foldl'` which in this case is faster, so if you were using it in a fast-paced game, or were handling a very large number of moves, you'd want to use that one.

As always, you can find functions by searching for their name or type on [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

There's also a foldr function which folds a list a different way. You can read about the difference between them in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280159/haskell-foldl-and-foldr/13280185). In short, though, `foldr` works like this:

```
foldr (?) s [x,y,z] = (x ? (y ? (z ? s)))
```

(The `r` in `foldr` is short for right, so it's there to help you remember that your starting value `s` will end up at the right but more importantly that the brackets are associated to the right.)

Comment: If the first move in the list is the first move to take, wouldn't you want a foldl?

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Hehe - I just logged on just now because while my children played I came to the same realisation. An edit is on the way.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Thanks. Sorted.

Comment: Great answer.  I just wanted to point out that if you refactor to make `move :: Pos -> Direction -> Pos` and `moves :: Pos -> [Direction] -> Pos`, then the implementation of `moves` reduces to `moves = foldl move`.

Comment: or `moves = flip $  foldl (flip move)` ^^