# SMLNJ powerset function

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml, powerset

I am trying to print the size of a list created from below power set function

```
fun add x ys = x :: ys;
   fun powerset ([])  = [[]]
   | powerset (x::xr) = powerset xr @ map (add x) (powerset xr) ;

val it = [[],[3],[2],[2,3],[1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]] : int list list;
```

I have the list size function

```
fun size xs = (foldr op+ 0 o map (fn x => 1)) xs;
```

I couldnt able to merge these two functions and get the result like

I need something like this:

```
[(0,[]),(1,[3]),(1,[2]),(2,[2,3]),(1,[1]),(2,[1,3]),(2,[1,2]),(3,[1,2,3])]
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Your definition for `powerset` makes little sense. In one clause you are using the name `powerset` and then in the very next line you seem to change your mind and want to call it `subsets1`. Which is it? Are you trying to define a function called `powerset` or are you trying to define `subsets1`? If `subsets1` has already been defined -- what it the code for it?

Comment: Thanks John for noticing it, It is a poweset function and not subset1

Answer (score 2):

You can get the length of a list using the built-in `List.length`.

You seem to forget to mention that you have the constraint that you can only use higher-order functions. (I am guessing you have this constraint because others these days are asking how to write powerset functions with this constraint, and using `foldr` to count, like you do, seems a little constructed.)

Your example indicates that you are trying to count each list in a list of lists, and not just the length of one list. For that you'd want to map the counting function across your list of lists. But that'd just give you a list of lengths, and your desired output seems to be a list of tuples containing both the length and the actual list.

Here are some hints:

1. You might as well [use `foldl` rather than `foldr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280159/haskell-foldl-and-foldr) since addition is associative.
2. You don't need to first `map (fn x => 1)` - this adds an unnecessary iteration of the list. You're probably doing this because folding seems complicated and you only just managed to write `foldr op+ 0`. This is symptomatic of not having understood the first argument of fold.

   Try, instead of `op+`, to write the fold expression using an anonymous function:

   ```
   fun size L = foldl (fn (x, acc) => ...) 0 L
   ```

   Compare this to `op+` which, if written like an anonymous function, would look like:

   ```
   fn (x, y) => x + y
   ```

   Folding with `op+` carries some very implicit uses of the + operator: You want to discard one operand (since not its value but its presence counts) and use the other one as an accumulating variable (which is better understood by calling it `acc` rather than `y`).

   If you're unsure what I mean about accumulating variable, consider this recursive version of `size`:

   ```
   fun size L =
       let fun sizeHelper ([], acc) = acc
             | sizeHelper (x::xs, acc) = sizeHelper (xs, 1+acc)
       in sizeHelper (L, 0) end
   ```

   Its helper function has an extra argument for carrying a result through recursive calls. This makes the function tail-recursive, and folding is one generalisation of this technique; the second argument to fold's helper function (given as an argument) is the accumulating variable. (The first argument to fold's helper function is a single argument rather than a list, unlike the explicitly recursive version of `size` above.)
3. Given your `size` function (aka `List.length`), you're only a third of the way, since

   ```
   size [[],[3],[2],[2,3],[1],[1,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
   ```

   gives you 8 and not `[(0,[]),(1,[3]),(1,[2]),(2,[2,3]),...)]`

   So you need to write another function that **(a)** applies `size` to each element, which would give you `[0,1,1,2,...]`, and **(b)** somehow combine that with the input list `[[],[3],[2],[2,3],...]`. You could do that either in two steps using `zip`/`map`, or in one step using only `foldr`.

   Try and write a `foldr` expression that *does nothing* to an input list `L`:

   ```
   foldr (fn (x, acc) => ...) [] L
   ```

   (Like with `op+`, doing `op::` instead of writing an anonymous function would be cheating.)

   Then think of each `x` as a list.

Comment: Thanks for the help but i should not use in-built functions like List.length

Comment: Have you read exactly and only the first line of this answer? :-)