# foldl versus foldr for merge operator

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold, combinators

Is the following statement equivalent?

```
foldr (++) [ ] = foldl (++) [ ]
```

I know that `foldr (+) 0 = fold (+) 0` is equivalent and for the operator (-) it's not, but how about the (++) operator ?
I think the result is a list with the same content but in another order. Is the order of the list relevant?

Comment: Hint: `(++)` is *associative*.

Comment: Have you tried testing them on various inputs? Maybe with `repeat [1]` as an input?

Comment: They behave very differently for infinite lists.

Comment: That `(+)` equivalence is also limited to finite lists.

Comment: In general, the order of the elements in two lists with the same contents is indeed relevant. Equality for lists depends on the order. Sometimes in a particular context you don't *care* about the order in a list, but in general a specific order is part of what makes a given a list what it is. There are other types for holding a collection of elements without order mattering.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo for many types the `(+)` equivalence also holds for infinite lists, e.g. `Int`, `Integer`, `Double`, etc. For all of those, both sides are equal to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: does not answer the question (sorry)

`foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`

`foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`

`(+)` is commutative, i.e. produces the same result if the arguments order is switched. E.g. `1+2` is the same as `2+1`.

Look at the type signature of `foldl` and `foldr`.

`foldl` takes a function `(b->a->b)` whose second argument is an element from the list.

On the other hand, `foldr` takes a function `(a->b->b)` whose first argument is an element from the list.

With `foldl`, there is an accumulation on the left (first argument). With `foldr`, there is an accumulation on the right (second argument).

`foldl` folds from left to right, `foldr` folds from right to left.

Technically, it's more complicated than that. For more information, see [https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27)

Comment: The important property is associativity, not commutativity. Take for example `foldr (.) id = foldl (.) id`. That holds (for finite lists), but `(.)` is not commutative.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, a visual representation is better than a thousand words:

[image: foldr][image: foldl]

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280185/5825294))

Comment: I don't think this answers the question if `foldr (++) [] = foldl (++) []` holds.

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions return the in order concatenation of all sublists in the rightmost argument, so they are *functionally* identical, at least for finite sublists.

Let's check using the Haskell `ghci` interpreter:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.5: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 ...
 λ> 
 λ> xss = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9]]
 λ>
 λ> foldr (++) [] xss == foldl (++) [] xss
 True
 λ> 
 λ> foldr (++) [] [[1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9]]
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 λ> 
 λ> foldl (++) [] [[1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9]]
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 λ>
```

But that's not the whole story. For example, any programmer who has been thru the usual lectures about sorting algorithms knows that bubble sort and QuickSort are *functionally* equivalent. Both algorithms return the ordered version of the input array.

But QuickSort is practical, and bubble sort is useless except for small input arrays.

It is a bit similar here.

Let's turn statistics on in our `ghci` interpreter:

```
 λ> 
 λ> :set +s
 λ> 
 λ> length $ foldl (++) [] (replicate 5000 [1,2,3,4])
 20000
 (3.31 secs, 4,124,759,752 bytes)
 λ> 
 λ> length $ foldl (++) [] (replicate 10000 [1,2,3,4])
 40000
 (16.94 secs, 17,172,001,352 bytes)
 λ>
```

So if we double the number of input sublists, the volume of memory allocations is multiplied by 4, not 2. The algorithm is *quadratic* here, hence horribly slow, like bubble sort.

And no, replacing `foldl` by its strict sibling `foldl'` will not help. The root of the problem is that operator (++) has to *duplicate* its left operand, because it is not feasible in Haskell to just alter its last pointer to next node, like you would do in C/C++. However, operator (++) can just use a simple pointer to its right operand, because the right operand is *immutable*, as is any Haskell named value.

In summary, for the left operand, immutability works against us. For the right operand, it works *for* us.

In the case of `foldl`, the left operand is the *accumulator*. So we repeatedly have to duplicate our (large and growing) accumulator. This is what breaks the *performance* symmetry between `foldl` and `foldr`.

We can readily check that the performance of `foldr` is much better:

```
 λ> 
 λ> length $ foldr (++) [] (replicate 5000 [1,2,3,4])
 20000
 (0.02 secs, 1,622,304 bytes)
 λ> 
 λ> length $ foldr (++) [] (replicate 10000 [1,2,3,4])
 40000
 (0.02 secs, 3,182,304 bytes)
 λ>
```

because here dynamic memory allocation is multiplied by 2, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how useful this is for you, but I wanted to use this as an excuse for learning Agda. So here's a formal proof:

Imports

```
import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as Eq
open Eq using (_≡_; refl; cong; sym)
open Eq.≡-Reasoning using (begin_; _≡⟨⟩_; step-≡; _∎)
```

Definitions

```
data List (A : Set) : Set where
  [] : List A
  _::_ : (x : A) (xs : List A) -> List A

variable 
  A : Set
  B : Set

foldr : (A -> B -> B) -> B -> List A -> B
foldr k z [] = z
foldr k z (x :: xs) = k x (foldr k z xs)

foldl : (B -> A -> B) -> B -> List A -> B
foldl k z [] = z
foldl k z (x :: xs) = foldl k (k z x) xs

_++_ : List A -> List A -> List A
[] ++ ys = ys
(x :: xs) ++ ys = x :: (xs ++ ys)
```

Theorems

```
++-assoc : ∀ (xs ys zs : List A)
        -> xs ++ (ys ++ zs) ≡ (xs ++ ys) ++ zs
++-assoc [] ys zs = refl
++-assoc (x :: xs) ys zs = cong (x ::_) (++-assoc xs ys zs)

++-[] : ∀ (xs : List A)
     -> xs ++ [] ≡ xs
++-[] [] = refl
++-[] (x :: xs) = cong (x ::_) (++-[] xs)

helper : ∀ (x : List A) (ys : List (List A))
      -> x ++ foldl _++_ [] ys ≡ foldl _++_ x ys
helper x [] = ++-[] x
helper x (y :: ys) =
  begin
    x ++ foldl _++_ [] (y :: ys)
  ≡⟨⟩
    x ++ foldl _++_ y ys
  ≡⟨ cong (x ++_) (sym (helper y ys)) ⟩
    x ++ (y ++ foldl _++_ [] ys)
  ≡⟨ ++-assoc x y (foldl _++_ [] ys) ⟩
    (x ++ y) ++ foldl _++_ [] ys
  ≡⟨ helper (x ++ y) ys ⟩
    foldl _++_ (x ++ y) ys
  ≡⟨⟩
    foldl _++_ x (y :: ys)
  ∎

proof : ∀ (xs : List (List A))
     -> foldr _++_ [] xs ≡ foldl _++_ [] xs
proof [] = refl
proof (x :: xs) =
  begin
    foldr _++_ [] (x :: xs)
  ≡⟨⟩
    x ++ foldr _++_ [] xs
  ≡⟨ cong (x ++_) (proof xs) ⟩
    x ++ foldl _++_ [] xs
  ≡⟨ helper x xs ⟩
    foldl _++_ x xs
  ≡⟨⟩
    foldl _++_ [] (x :: xs)
  ∎
```

I hope that is kind of readable even if you only know Haskell.

This was more work than I expected. It's not obvious knowing only associativity of `_++_`.

Oh, and I'm sure it is not so hard to generalize this to any associative operation with an identity element. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

And finally I should note that this only holds for finite lists.

Comment: Wow, the Agda code is quite fancy! Formal proofs would indeed take some effort, which is I think why dep-type langs are yet to gain significant traction.

Comment: @Abastro, I didn't really mean that writing it in Agda was more work than expected, but rather that the proof/formalization itself requires more work than I expected. I think it is way too easy to be overconfident in the correctness of your programs.

Comment: Oh, was not specifically pointing out Agda, it is a great language. I was talking about formal proofs in general. Imho less formal proof could be good enough with much less effort, as that is also what happens in mathematics research.