# foldr & foldl Haskell explanation

Tags: haskell

We have been asked to answer whether `foldr` or `foldl` is more efficient.

I am not sure, but doesn't it depend on what I am doing, especially what I want to reach with my functions?

Is there a difference from case to case or can one say that `foldr` or `foldl` is better , because...

Is there a general answer ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh , thanks for that. But I thought there would be a difference regarding to memory etc. Does foldr need more steps than foldl ?

Comment: As you imply, it depends on what you want to do. Although you could say that foldr is "better" because you can implement foldl in terms of foldr but not vice versa.

Comment: See [Foldr Foldl Foldl'](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl') in the Wiki for more details.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A fairly canonical source on this question is [Foldr Foldl Foldl'](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl') on the Haskell Wiki. In summary, depending on how strictly you can combine elements of the list and what the result of your fold is you may decide to choose either `foldr` or `foldl'`. It's rarely the right choice to choose `foldl`.

Generally, this is a good example of how you have to keep in mind the laziness and strictness of your functions in order to compute efficiently in Haskell. In strict languages, tail-recursive definitions and TCO are the name of the game, but those kinds of definitions may be too "unproductive" (not lazy enough) for Haskell leading to the production of useless thunks and fewer opportunities for optimization.

### When to choose `foldr`

If the operation that *consumes* the result of your fold can operate lazily and your combining function is non-strict in its right argument, then `foldr` is usually the right choice. The quintessential example of this is the `nonfold`. First we see that `(:)` is non-strict on the right

```
head (1 : undefined)
1
```

Then here's `nonfold` written using `foldr`

```
nonfoldr :: [a] -> [a]
nonfoldr = foldr (:) []
```

Since `(:)` creates lists lazily, an expression like `head . nonfoldr` can be very efficient, requiring just one folding step and forcing just the head of the input list.

```
head (nonfoldr [1,2,3])
head (foldr (:) [] [1,2,3])
head (1 : foldr (:) [] [2,3])
1
```

#### Short-circuiting

A very common place where laziness wins out is in short-circuiting computations. For instance, `lookup :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool` can be more productive by returning the moment it sees a match.

```
lookupr :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
lookupr x = foldr (\y inRest -> if x == y then True else inRest) False
```

The short-circuiting occurs because we discard `isRest` in the first branch of the `if`. The same thing implemented in `foldl'` can't do that.

```
lookupl :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
lookupl x = foldl' (\wasHere y -> if wasHere then wasHere else x == y) False

lookupr 1 [1,2,3,4]
foldr fn False [1,2,3,4]
if 1 == 1 then True else (foldr fn False [2,3,4])
True

lookupl 1 [1,2,3,4]
foldl' fn False [1,2,3,4]
foldl' fn True [2,3,4]
foldl' fn True [3,4]
foldl' fn True [4]
foldl' fn True []
True
```

### When to choose `foldl'`

If the consuming operation or the combining requires that the entire list is processed before it can proceed, then `foldl'` is usually the right choice. Often the best check for this situation is to ask yourself whether your combining function is strict---if it's strict in the first argument then your whole list must be forced anyway. The quintessential example of this is `sum`

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum = foldl' (+) 0
```

since `(1 + 2)` cannot be reasonably consumed prior to actually doing the addition (Haskell isn't smart enough to know that `1 + 2 >= 1` without first evaluating `1 + 2`) then we don't get any benefit from using `foldr`. Instead, we'll use the *strict combining* property of `foldl'` to make sure that we evaluate things as eagerly as needed

```
sum [1,2,3]
foldl' (+) 0 [1,2,3]
foldl' (+) 1 [2,3]
foldl' (+) 3 [3]
foldl' (+) 6 []
6
```

Note that if we pick `foldl` here we don't get quite the right result. While `foldl` has the same associativity as `foldl'`, it doesn't force the combining operation with `seq` like `foldl'` does.

```
sumWrong :: Num a => [a] -> a
sumWrong = foldl (+) 0

sumWrong [1,2,3]
foldl (+) 0 [1,2,3]
foldl (+) (0 + 1) [2,3]
foldl (+) ((0 + 1) + 2) [3]
foldl (+) (((0 + 1) + 2) + 3) []
(((0 + 1) + 2) + 3)
((1       + 2) + 3)
(3             + 3)
6
```

### What happens when we choose wrong?

We get extra, useless thunks (space leak) if we choose `foldr` or `foldl` when in `foldl'` sweet spot and we get extra, useless evaluation (time leak) if we choose `foldl'` when `foldr` would have been a better choice.

```
nonfoldl :: [a] -> [a]
nonfoldl = foldl (:) []

head (nonfoldl [1,2,3])
head (foldl (:) []  [1,2,3])
head (foldl (:) [1]   [2,3])
head (foldl (:) [1,2]   [3])  -- nonfoldr finished here, O(1)
head (foldl (:) [1,2,3]  [])
head [1,2,3]
1                             -- this is O(n)

sumR :: Num a => [a] -> a
sumR = foldr (+) 0

sumR [1,2,3]
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]
1 + foldr (+) 0 [2, 3]      -- thunks begin
1 + (2 + foldr (+) 0 [3])
1 + (2 + (3 + foldr (+) 0)) -- O(n) thunks hanging about
1 + (2 + (3 + 0)))
1 + (2 + 3)
1 + 5
6                           -- forced O(n) thunks
```

Comment: Extremely good answer. Bravo. I have one question, though. I have a feeling you're using the word "productive" very deliberately and with some special meaning. Is that so, and in that case, what is that meaning?

Comment: I am! I mean it in reference to the productivity requirement on codata in total programming languages like Coq and Agda. Normally infinite loops are disallowed in total programming languages, but they are sometimes useful. To model this you introduce the notion of codata which are "well-behaved" (possibly) infinite objects such that you can use them to program with infinite loops without violating termination. In this case "well-behaved" means "productive" means that you dn't have an infinite loop that just spins in place---it must eventually produce a new result.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson `lookupr` may short circuit the computation or not. In the latter case it behaves as if it were strict in its second argument and hence traverses the whole list. Doesn't this mean - strictly speaking - that `lookupr` might cause a stack overflow, i.e. is a partial function?

Comment: @ftor You're correct to note that evaluating `lookupr` will completely evaluate it's second argument if its a failed lookup, but this will not stack overflow. Haskell's runtime generally works in a stack-safe fashion. It's possible to achieve them but you have to be more clever than this.

Answer (score 6):

In languages with strict/eager evaluation, folding from the left can be done in constant space, while folding from the right requires linear space (over the number of elements of the list).  Because of this, many people who first approach Haskell come over with this preconception.

But **that rule of thumb doesn't work in Haskell**, because of lazy evaluation.  It's possible in Haskell to write constant space functions with `foldr`.  Here is one example:

```
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find p = foldr (\x next -> if p x then Just x else next) Nothing
```

Let's try hand-evaluating `find even [1, 3, 4]`:

```
-- The definition of foldr, for reference:
foldr f z [] = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)

find even (1:3:4:[])
    = foldr (\x next -> if even x then Just x else next) (1:3:4:[])
    = if even 1 then Just 1 else foldr (\x next -> if even x then Just x else next) (3:4:[])
    = foldr (\x next -> if even x then Just x else next) (3:4:[])
    = if even 3 then Just 3 else foldr (\x next -> if even x then Just x else next) (4:[])
    = foldr (\x next -> if even x then Just x else next) (4:[])
    = if even 4 then Just 4 else foldr (\x next -> if even x then Just x else next) []
    = Just 4
```

The size of the expressions in the intermediate steps has a constant upper bound—this actually means that this evaluation can be carried out in constant space.

Another reason why `foldr` in Haskell can run in constant space is because of the [list fusion optimizations in GHC](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/ghc-doc/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html#idp54656704).  GHC in many cases can optimize a `foldr` into a constant-space loop over a constant-space producer.  It cannot generally do that for a left fold.

Nonetheless, left folds in Haskell *can* be written to use tail recursion, which *can* lead to performance benefits.  The thing is that for this to actually succeed you need to be very careful about laziness—naïve attempts at writing a tail recursive algorithm normally lead to linear-space execution, because of an accumulation of unevaluated expressions.

Takeaway lessons:

1. When you're starting out in Haskell, try to use library functions from `Prelude` and `Data.List` as much as possible, because they've been carefully written to exploit performance features like list fusion.
2. If you need to fold a list, try `foldr` first.
3. Never use `foldl`, use `foldl'` (the version that avoids unevaluated expressions).
4. If you want to use tail-recursion in Haskell, first you need to understand how evaluation works—otherwise you may make things worse.

Comment: Good point made on the "order of attempts"! First attempts are better off as `foldr`s which are optimized to `foldl'`s if the strictness works out.

Answer (score 2):

**(Please read the comments on this post. Some interesting points were made and what I wrote here isn't completely true!)**

It depends. foldl is usually faster since it's tail recursive, meaning (sort of), that all computation is done in-place and there's no call-stack. For reference:

```
foldl f a [] = a
foldl f a (x:xs) = foldl f (f a x) xs
```

To run foldr we do need a call stack, since there is a "pending" computation for `f`.

```
foldr f a [] = a
foldr f a (x:xs) = f x (foldr f a xs)
```

On the other hand, foldr can short-circuit if f is not strict in its first argument. It's *lazier* in a way. For example, if we define a new product

```
prod 0 x = 0
prod x 0 = 0
prod x y = x*y
```

Then

```
foldr prod 1 [0...n]
```

Takes constant time in n, but

```
foldl prod 1 [0...n]
```

takes linear time. (This will not work using `(*)`, since it does not check if any argument is 0. So we create a non-strict version. Thanks to Ingo and Daniel Lyons for pointing it out in the comments)

Comment: I see at least 3 severe problems with this post.

Comment: 1. As it stands, foldl uses to build up huge thunks, which, in the end may very well lead to stack overflow.

Comment: 2. The arguments in the expoansion of foldr are in wrong order.

Comment: Point taken on argument order, I've been using ML which implements foldl and foldr with the same type. I don't understand your first point though.

Comment: 3. I don't see how foldr (*) and foldl (*) make any difference for primitive types where (*) is usually a primitive operation that doesn't check for the "easy" case. What you want to say is that, if the function is non-strict in its right argument, then it may benefit with foldr.

Comment: Nice as it would be, Haskell isn't smart enough to stop the computation with `foldr (*) 1 [0..n]`. Try it with a large value of N and `:set +s`, e.g.: `Prelude> foldr (*) 1 [0..100000]
0
(16.67 secs, 9959201448 bytes)`

Comment: True again. Way to destroy my post :)! Here's a good explanation on why it causes a stack overflow, see the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429634/foldl-is-tail-recursive-so-how-come-foldr-runs-faster-than-foldl

Comment: Sorry for that, @Guido, I hope you don't take it personally. But it's about the truth, you know ....

Comment: Of course not! Those were great observations. I now remember messing with foldl, seeing stack overflows and being puzzled about it. Now I know why! So thank you!

Comment: This is perhaps alos because of your experiences with ML, which is strict, AFAIK, and so foldl is probably behaving like foldl' in Haskell.

Comment: Note also the comment in that answer, tail recursion has a different implication in haskell (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons)