# Divide Int to Int in Haskell

Tags: haskell, int

I want a function that calculates average mark from a given list of marks. This is what I have made so far:

```
getAverageRate :: [Int]->Int
getAverageRate marks = (fromIntegral (foldr (+) 0 marks))/(fromIntegral (length marks))
```

What I am trying to do is to get the sum of all marks in the list by using 'foldr' then divide by 'length marks'. Despite I already use 'fromIntegral' this error still appears and I can not find the problem.

```
No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `/'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Int)
In the expression:
  (fromIntegral (foldr (+) 0 marks)) / (fromIntegral (length marks))
In an equation for `getAverageRate':
    getAverageRate marks
      = (fromIntegral (foldr (+) 0 marks))
        / (fromIntegral (length marks))
```

Comment: By calling `fromIntegral`, you're asking for a conversion from `Int` to some other type. But by restricting the return type of your function to `Int`, the type you're painstakingly converting those `Int`s to is... `Int`!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The thing is that `Int` represents an integer, so it doesn't make sense to be able to divide it since most divisions result in things which aren't integers.

Happily we have `div`, which is integer division, so you could do

```
 average :: [Int] -> Int
 average [] = error "Can't average an empty list"
 average xs = sum xs `div` length xs
```

If you don't want to use integer division, then we could do something like

```
 average :: [Int] -> Double
 average xs = fromIntegral (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

which just promotes everything to a `Double` for division.

Finally you could choose a method for rounding and go with what you have

```
 average xs = round $ fromIntegral (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

(Friendly neighborhood warning that `sum` is evil and uses `foldl` instead of `foldl'` so be sure to compile with `-O2` when using long lists)

Comment: As someone who is new to haskell, why is `sum` evil?

Comment: @devshorts it's based on `foldl` which can stackoverflow in situations  you wouldn't expect. It works with `-O2` though search foldl vs foldl'

Comment: Excuse my self plugging here, but for Haskell beginners here's a description of why `foldl'` is better than `foldl`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I think you forgot a link? I'd actually love a good tutorial to point to so please share :)

Comment: Oh, I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356742/foldr-foldl-haskell-explanation/20359256#20359256 Thanks for notifying me

Comment: I'd also add that for unsigned integers it's better to use `quot` and `rem` rather than `div` and `mod` – they are slightly faster due to the different approach to sign processing.