# Accessing the Accumulator & Element in `foldl`

Tags: scala, haskell, fold

In Scala's `foldLeft`, I know how to access the `accumulator` and `element` values in Scala, but not Haskell.

I could use `foldLeft` to find out, between 1 and 100, how many numbers have a remainder of 1 when divided by 3:

```
scala> List.range(1, 101).foldLeft(0){ (acc, elem) =>
     |    if (elem % 3 == 1) acc + 1
     |    else acc
     | }
res2: Int = 33
```

How can I do the same in Haskell?

Comment: `Data.List` has many useful functions similar to Scala's List. `Data.List.foldl` is scala's `List.foldLeft`. `foldl` is imported by `Prelude`, but watch out for other useful stuff - it may need importing explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a direct translation of your Scala code to Haskell:

```
foldl (\acc x -> if x `mod` 3 == 1 then acc + 1 else acc) 0 [1..100]
```

In Haskell, because of laziness of it, [using `foldl` usually is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082324/foldl-versus-foldr-behavior-with-infinite-lists), a better choose is `foldl'` or `foldr`, here is the `foldr` version:

```
foldr (\x acc -> if x `mod` 3 == 1 then acc + 1 else acc) 0 [1..100]
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "why" behind: `In Haskell, because of laziness of it, using foldl usually is not a good idea`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Because GHC is lazy, it will build up a very large list of "thunks", or computation promises with how `foldl` is implemented, and it won't evaluate them until the entire list has been traversed.  The `foldl'` variant is strict in its arguments, so it will evaluate the fold while traversing the list, and `foldr`'s implementation lets it generate one thunk at a time rather than traversing the entire spine of the list in one go.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Beside the exaplation given by @bheklilr, you could also searcin in SO using keywords `[haskell] foldr foldl`, there are lots of relevant questions and answers.

Answer (score 5):

There's essentially a 1-to-1 correspondence:

```hs
mySum :: [Int] -> Int
mySum xs = foldl (\acc elem ->
    if elem `mod` 3 == 1
        then acc + 1
        else acc
    ) 0 xs
```

Other than syntax and order of arguments, there's no real difference.

---

For future readers, it is recommended to avoid using `foldl` in practice.  Due to laziness in `foldl`'s implementation, space leaks can occur for large lists.  Instead, there is a strict version `foldl'` which can be used as a drop-in replacement or the right fold `foldr` which has a bit format:

```hs
mySum xs = foldr (\elem acc ->    -- order of arguments swapped
    if elem `mod` 3 == 1
        then acc + 1
        else acc
    ) 0 xs
```

Comment: Also, you should point out that using `Data.List.foldl'` will avoid a space leak.

Comment: In fact `foldr` in this scenario will lead to stack space overflow on sufficiently large input (try [1..10000000]) while `foldl'` and `foldl` won't. I believe nowadays GHC with `-O2` now can figure out and remove unnecessary laziness, that is why `foldl` does not stack overflow here.

Comment: @Ed'ka I am not certain why `foldl` would stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather similar:

```
foldl (\acc x -> if (x `mod` 3 == 1) then acc + 1 else acc) 0 [1..100]
```

The first argument to foldl is the lambda, the second is the accumulator `0` and the third is the range of values.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429634/foldl-is-tail-recursive-so-how-come-foldr-runs-faster-than-foldl) to understand the differences between foldl, foldl' and foldr.