# What kinds of recursions are used in the definitions of `foldr` and `foldl`?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fold

```
foldr   ::  (a  ->  b   ->  b)  ->  b   ->  [a] ->  b
foldr   f   v   [] =    v
foldr   f   v   (x:xs)  =   f   x   (foldr  f   v   xs)
```

and

```
foldl   ::  (a  ->  b   ->  a)  ->  a   ->  [b] ->  a
foldl   f   v   [] =    v
foldl   f   v   (x:xs)  =   foldl   f   (f  v   x)  xs
```

seem to use different kinds of recursions.

What  kinds of recursions are used in the  definitions of `foldr` and `foldl`?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what sort of thing you mean by a "kind of recursion"?

Comment: I think I know it: non tail and tail recursions.

Comment: It is true that one of them is tail recursive and one of them is not tail recursive. Is there a description of tail recursion that you are working from? If so, what parts of it do you understand and what parts of it do you not understand? Giving information like this helps us answer the question in a way that helps you to better understand. Try to provide a bit more information like this, when possible (especially definitions like that and what you do and don't understand about those definitions).

Comment: Relevant: [*foldl is tail recursive, so how come foldr runs faster than foldl?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3429634/2751851)

Answer (score 3):

`foldl` uses tail recursion.

`foldr` uses *guarded recursion*, the recursion being guarded by `f`'s laziness (if any).

- see also: [Does Haskell have tail-recursive optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13042353/849891)